# Scrapy crawl spider on pages with infinite scroll

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am attempting to use a scrapy crawl spider to follow links on a website with infinite scroll, scrape information from the urls it follows, and then continue to follow links and scrape information. I have found advice on this for scrapy in general, but not much for crawl spiders. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import re


class ItsySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['citizen.digital']
    start_urls = ['https://www.citizen.digital/search?query=the']
    

    rules = (
        Rule(follow="True"),
        )


    def parse(self, response):
        
        base = 'http://cms.citizen.digital/api/v2/search?page={}'
        data = response.json
        current_page = data["current_page"]
        
        for page in range(2, 10):
            next_page_url=base.format(current_page+page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_next)
        
    
    def parse_next(self, response):
        
        yield{
            'url': response.url,
            'date': response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').re(r'(?i)(?<=datepublished": ")..........'),  
            }
```

As you can see, I want to load 10 pages on the infinite scroll site and follow on links on those pages. Then I want to extract url and date from the urls it follows, and then continue to follow links and extract info.

I do not have experience with json, so I wonder if I have made a mistake there. Here is an example response for loading the second page on the infinite scroll site:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 186903,
            "slug": "there-are-plans-to-harm-me-but-i-will-not-be-intimidated-a-defiant-nyoro-says-275851",
            "thumbnail": "https:\/\/images.citizen.digital\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/09\/ndindi-nyoro-main-e1568106330665.jpg",
            "description": " ",
            "type": "news",
            "title": "\u2018There are plans to harm me but I will not be intimidated,\u2019 a defiant Nyoro says",
            "date": "12.05pm, September 10, 2019(EAT)",
            "menu": {
                "id": 14,
                "slug": "news"
            },
            "author": "Wangui Ngechu"
        },
        {
            "id": 106999,
            "slug": "mwalala-lashes-out-at-intimidated-referees-after-leopards-defeat-243224",
            "thumbnail": null,
            "description": " ",
            "type": "news",
            "title": "Mwalala lashes out at \u2018intimidated referees\u2019 after Leopards defeat",
            "date": "12.20pm, April 29, 2019(EAT)",
            "menu": {
                "id": 7,
                "slug": "sports"
            },
            "author": "Geoffrey Mwamburi"
        },
        {
            "id": 271435,
            "slug": "why-men-are-intimidated-by-successful-women-133180",
            "thumbnail": "http:\/\/images.citizen.digital\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/08\/Men.jpg",
            "description": " ",
            "type": "news",
            "title": "Why men are intimidated by successful women",
            "date": "05.11pm, August 29, 2018(EAT)",
            "menu": {
                "id": 4,
                "slug": "entertainment"
            },
            "author": "Sheila Jerotich"
        },
        {
            "id": 271671,
            "slug": "besides-my-wife-these-are-the-only-people-who-can-intimidate-me-duale-132744",
            "thumbnail": null,
            "description": " ",
            "type": "news",
            "title": "Besides my wife, these are the only people who can intimidate me \u2013 Duale",
            "date": "05.13pm, August 02, 2018(EAT)",
            "menu": {
                "id": 4,
                "slug": "entertainment"
            },
            "author": "eDaily Reporter"
        },
        {
            "id": 209728,
            "slug": "nys-boss-richard-ndubai-will-intimidate-witnesses-if-freed-dpp-203602",
            "thumbnail": "https:\/\/images.citizen.digital\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/06\/ndubai.png",
            "description": " ",
            "type": "news",
            "title": "NYS boss Richard Ndubai will intimidate witnesses if freed: DPP",
            "date": "06.15pm, June 11, 2018(EAT)",
            "menu": {
                "id": 14,
                "slug": "news"
            },
            "author": "Dzuya Walter"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "total": 15,
            "count": 5,
            "per_page": 5,
            "current_page": 2,
            "total_pages": 3,
            "links": {
                "previous": "http:\/\/cms.citizen.digital\/api\/v2\/search?page=1",
                "next": "http:\/\/cms.citizen.digital\/api\/v2\/search?page=3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it using `scrapy crawl test -O test.csv`, it returns an empty csv file.

Comment: It looks like you have already API access, why using scrapy then? Based on what I see and the response you are getting, you could just use the python `requests` library and parse the information as a dictionary by doing: `response.json()`

Comment: @EnriqueBet I am using scrapy because I want to scrape the entire domain (or as much as possible). I plan scrape more than just the 10 pages and also intend to scrape more information. I used the above code just as an example

Comment: Also I do not have API access, so maybe that is part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First scrape the html page for the api key, and api base url (optionally, youcan also just type it). Then add the api key to the headers and start scraping the api

```py
import scrapy
import logging
import codecs


class ItsySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['citizen.digital']
    start_urls = ['https://www.citizen.digital/search?query=the']

    custom_settings = {'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.4}
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content_Type": "application/json",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "cms.citizen.digital",
        "Origin": "https://www.citizen.digital",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Referer": "https://www.citizen.digital/",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        apiKey = response.xpath('//script/text()').re(r'apiKey:\"(.*?)\",')
        apiBaseURL = response.xpath('//script/text()').re(r'apiBaseURL:\"(.*?)\",')

        if not apiKey:
            logging.log(logging.ERROR, 'Could not retrieve the api key')
            return

        if not apiBaseURL:
            logging.log(logging.ERROR, 'Could not retrieve the api base url')
            return

        apiKey = apiKey[0]
        apiBaseURL = codecs.decode(apiBaseURL[0], 'unicode-escape')
        apiBaseURL += '/search?term=the&limit=5&text_limit=300&platform=web'

        self.headers['Api-Key'] = apiKey

        yield scrapy.Request(url=apiBaseURL+'&page=1',
                             headers=self.headers,
                             cb_kwargs={'page_number': 1, 'apiBaseURL': apiBaseURL},
                             callback=self.parse_api)

    def parse_api(self, response, page_number, apiBaseURL):
        json_data = response.json()

        for data in json_data['data']:
            yield data

        # if you want to scrape all the pages of the api:
        # if json_data['meta']['pagination']['current_page'] == json_data['meta']['pagination']['total_pages']:
        # since you want to scrape 10 pages:
        if json_data['meta']['pagination']['current_page'] == 10:
            logging.log(logging.INFO, 'Finished scraping')
            return

        # go to the next page
        page_number += 1
        yield scrapy.Request(url=apiBaseURL+f'&page={str(page_number)}',
                             headers=self.headers,
                             cb_kwargs={'page_number': page_number, 'apiBaseURL': apiBaseURL},
                             callback=self.parse_api)

    def parse_next(self, response):
        yield{
            'url': response.url,
            'date': response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').re(r'(?i)(?<=datepublished": ")..........'),
        }
```

Comment: This works perfectly for loading pages and scraping information about the articles. Thank you. However, the output is not quite what I was aiming for. When I run it with `scrapy crawl test -O test.csv`, the output csv file has info on the id, slug, thumbnail, etc. of each loaded article, rather than the anticipated url and date (the last couple lines from the code), which could be extracted from the actual website of each loaded article.

Comment: As a next step, I hope to following all of the links in each of the websites, then scrape from all of the new websites, then follow their links, etc. (i.e., crawl the domain, which is why the crawl spider is needed).

Comment: @jedmund, you gave the json data (slug, thumbnail, etc) as an example in your post, so you don't want them? Do you want only the url and date? You can crate the full url from the "slug".

Comment: I've realized a complete solution is to run the script you provided and use the outputted json data to construct a list of urls. Then I can use that list as the starting urls for a crawl. Thanks!